# CIRandomGenerator filter can not be applied to a filter

Tags: objective-c, filter, core-image

My code returns null when i try to apply CIRandomGenerator.
The application just crashes when i enter in the filter page, i am coding using objective c.

```
if([filterName isEqualToString:@"CIRandomGenerator"]){
        // parameters
  [filter  setValue:[[CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIRandomGenerator"] valueForKey:@"outputImage"] forKey:@"inputImage"];


 CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
    CIImage *outputImage = [filter outputImage];
    CGImageRef cgImage = [context createCGImage:outputImage fromRect:[outputImage extent]];

    UIImage *result = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage];

    CGImageRelease(cgImage);

    return result;
```

Comment: While I use Swift, I can read Obj-C. `valueForKey:@"outputImage"` - if the syntax is correct, is it null? What line is things crashing on?

Answer (score 0):

`CIRandomGenerator` generates an image with infinite extent. You need to crop the result before you can render it into a `CGImage`, e.g.:

```
CIImage *outputImage = [[filter outputImage] imageByCroppingToRect: CGRectMake(0, 0, 500, 500)];
```